# How to get Webpshere to work with NetBeans 6.9

Tags: netbeans, websphere

I have seen that on nightly builds of Netbeans RC 6.9, there was Webpshere support, as in some previous versions.

Does anyone have any clue why it is still not supported on latest Netbeans 6.9 and when will it be available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will never be available again. That is the best guess as this moment as Oracle is a pretty strong competitor of IBM, and they nixed the support on purpose.